# No .app bundle found in the package, while uploading with Application Loader

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle

I know there are already several questions on the subject, but I am really desperate. I don't know what else to do than to look for an advice here.

So, I have an app ready to be uploaded.

I have checked all the pre-steps, before trying to upload:

- Bundle ID matches in info.plist, iTunesConnect, Apple developer, Provisioning profile
- Game works perfectly when I run it on the device, in app purchase works with a test user, and not a single issue appears

Here are some screenshots with some info:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

What I have noticed is that there isn't any Provisioning Profile selected:
[image: No Provisioning profile selected]

Yet, when I select the provisioning profile I made earlier, I get this error. When I clock "Fix" it changes it back to none provisioning profile selected.
I don't know if that's the cause of the trouble
[image]

All in all, this is the Error I get:
[image]

This is my first time that I'm uploading an app with in app purchase. So I might missed some obvious step. I really hope that somebody will see the problem here, because I've been trying to fight this for 2 days now :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you see "iPhone Developer" in the code signing identity, that means Xcode will automatically select a matching identity to sign the app (It doesn't mean that no profile is selected).

From what I can see it looks like "iPhone Developer" is chosen for both Debug and Release configurations which will likely cause a problem because you cannot submit a Developer signed app to the App Store, it must be signed with a Distribution certificate and Distribution profile.

You will need to ensure that you have created a Distribution Certificate and profile to sign your app with before archiving it and submitting it via Xcode.

I would recommend you read up on how app store distribution works from the Apple documentation here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Then if you still are having trouble, read the trouble shooting guide from the docs here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Troubleshooting/Troubleshooting.html

Comment: after creating distribution goto product->Archice->select validation if not found any erros it will work perfectly

Comment: I will look into it and let you know :)

Answer (score 2):

I have had a similar problem. We received an APP from an external provider and re-signed the APP ourselves using our own certificate and provisioning profile. When uploading the APP with Application Loader I received the error ITMS-90167: No .app bundles found in the package.

I have sierra installed on my Mac and I am using XCode 8.0 but had an old version of Application Loader (3.0) that was installed separately. Using this version of Application Loader I got the message. If I instead used the Application Loader that is part of Xcode (from the XCode/Open Developer Tool menu), ie version 3.6 everything worked out great and the ipa file was successfully uploaded to ITunesConnect.